# Subscribe plugin

Tags: users, plugins

I started a project in Craft, but I think I need a plugin. The idea is to generate 2,000 registration codes for a subscription in the site and the only way to access the site is to register using any of the 2,000 codes that are printed on cards. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you correctly then it sounds completely doable.

You'd need to create a Craft [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) that generated the 2,000 codes to use and save them somewhere (probably the database).

Then you'd write a [registration form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) for the front-end of your site that posted to your plugin's [controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers) and passing along any registration code they've entered.  Your plugin would then validate that code against the database and call Craft's [UsersService->saveUser()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UsersService#saveUser-detail) if it is valid, otherwise return an appropriate error.